# Patch Storage for a CSound Instrument

Tags: raspberry-pi, midi-instrument, csound

My CSound instrument updates a handful of parameters via MIDI controller messages. It needs to be able to store and retrieve parameter sets (patches) and update the parameters on MIDI patch change messages.

Is there a CSound way to do this other than building it from Python opcodes?

I think I could build a patch manager in PureData, but would that tax a Raspberry PI beyond usefulness? Would a PureData program hit the CPU at all when not busy changing patches?

Comment: I thought of a better way to do this - use nodejs. Here is the project in progress: https://github.com/jbeuckm/RaspPi-Resonant-EQ

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in native Csound code. Simply write the the details to disk and recall them later at any stage. You can use any of the file writing opcodes such a fout, or foutk for this.

https://csound.github.io/docs/manual/foutk.html

To read the values from disk you can use fink:

https://csound.github.io/docs/manual/fink.html